# Hibernate doubles foreign key in one-to-many

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have parent entity for example named as `Parent`, it extends `Base` entity, also i have children entities named `Children`, and there is relation one-to-many in Parent, meaning `Set<Children>`, but in `Children`, parent is described just as `Base`, and therefore hibernate creates two foreign keys in children's table, but what most annoying - one of them is DELETE-CASCADE, and another is not, which cause errors when i'am trying to delete parent, **how can i either have one foreign key(without strictly relation to parent as `Parent` in `Children`), or at least fix violating key without DELETE-CASCADE?**

**Code**(not all, just relative)**:**

Base.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="Base" table="controls">
    <id name="id">
    <subclass name="Parent" discriminator-value="Parent">
         <set name="items" cascade="save-update, delete-orphan" order-by="orderNumber asc" lazy="false" inverse="true" sort="natural">
             <key column="controlId" on-delete="cascade"/>
             <one-to-many class="children"/>
         </set>
     </subclass>
</class>
```

Children.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="controls.FAQItem" table="faq_item">
     <id name="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <many-to-one name="base" column="controlId"/>
</class>
```

Parent.java:

```
public class Parent extends Base{
    private Set<Children> items;
    //getters  and setters
}
```

Children.class:

```
public class Children {
    private Base base;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Errors:

```
    Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`db_cofp`.`children`, CONSTRAINT `FK3534269CB50AD2C` FOREIGN KEY (`controlId`) 
REFERENCES `controls` (`id`))
```

Show create table:
*just relative end

```
KEY `FK3534269CC41202F7` (`controlId`),
KEY `FK3534269CB50AD2C` (`controlId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK3534269CB50AD2C` FOREIGN KEY (`controlId`) REFERENCES `controls` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK3534269CC41202F7` FOREIGN KEY (`controlId`) REFERENCES `controls` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Hope i showed all that matters, note thet `Base`and`Children` extends BasicEntity class with id, didn't wrote it as it just have `int id` and getters and setters

Comment: I know i can just delete another key and everything will work fine, but i guess it is not the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by rewriting mappings to:

Base.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="Base" table="controls">
    <id name="id">
    <subclass name="Parent" discriminator-value="Parent">
         <set name="items" cascade="save-update, delete-orphan" order-by="orderNumber asc" lazy="false" sort="natural">
             <key column="controlId"/>
             <one-to-many class="children"/>
         </set>
     </subclass>
</class>
```

Children.hbm.xml:

```
<class name="controls.FAQItem" table="faq_item">
     <id name="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <many-to-one name="base" column="controlId" class="Parent"/>
</class>
```